# Dont understand for each loop with two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Got this example from my book:

```
public class ForEach3 {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int sum=0;
    int numbers [][]=new int[3][5];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            numbers[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }


    for(int x[]:numbers)
    {
        for(int y:x)
        {
            System.out.println("Number is: "+y);
            sum+=y;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I understand everything until it comes to this loop:

```
or(int x[]:numbers)
    {
        for(int y:x)
```

Why we had to make this loop ? : for(int y:x)
Thats the part which confuse me a lot, i know how to do basic for each loop with basic array, but this confuse me a lot when i use two dimensional array..

Comment: uncommon syntax for `for(int[] x : numbers)` if that helps you understand

Comment: Still dont understand it, sorry..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so consider this code:

```
for(int x[] : numbers) {
    for(int y : x) {
        System.out.println("Number is: " + y);
    }
}
```

Now, on the first line, you see some odd syntax. The `int x[]` is saying the same things as `int[] x`. (All it is, is a different way of saying the same thing.) Basically, you're declaring an array. Now the `foreach` loop takes each element in the array you specify after the `:`, or `numbers`, and places it into the variable you declared before the `:`, or `x`.

Now, the best way to understand this code is to understand how 2D arrays work. They aren't some new special thing, all a 2D array is, is an *array of arrays*. Instead of each element being a value, like in a traditional array, each element is a whole other array, with it's own set of values. So let's look at the top line of code again.

```
for(int x[] : numbers) {
```

This, in english, translates to, "For each of the elements in `numbers`, place it's value in `x` and run the code below." Remember that because `numbers` is an *array of arrays*, each of it's elements is an array. So the code runs through the first iteration, and retrieves the first element in `numbers` (at index 0), which is an array of `int`s. Then, it runs the code below:

```
for(int y : x) {
    System.out.println("Number is: " + y);
}
```

The top line of code can be translated to english as follows: "For each of the elements in `x`, place it's value in `y` and run the code below." So, it does just that. The code runs through the first iteration and retrieves the first element in `x`, which is an `int`. Then, it runs the code:

```
System.out.println("Number is: " + y);
```

Of course, that prints out the value it retrieved. Then, the inner `for` loop keeps going through the array `x` until it has reached the end. At this point, just like any other `for` loop, it exits.

Now, remember that you are still only on the first iteration of the `for(int x[] : numbers)` loop. So now that all the code inside has run, it retrieves the next element in `numbers`, or the next array. (Because `numbers` is an *array of arrays*) It runs the code below again, repeating until it has run the code for every element (or array) in `numbers`.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask me questions in the comments.

### Edit:

For your questions in the comments, let's look at this graphically.

[image: Graphic Representation of 2D Array]

So the orange box here is `numbers`. It is an array. Each of it's elements in one of the blue boxes. (For a total of 3). Now, look at the top blue box. It is an array. The top blue box is `numbers[0]`, or, (during the first iteration of the outer loop) `x`. Now look at the inside of the top blue box, at the green boxes. Each of the blue box's elements is represented by a green box. Each green box is an `int`. The first green box in the first blue box is (during the first iteration of the outer loop), `x[0]`, or (during the first iteration of both the outer and inner loops), `y`. So the outer loop is looping through all of the blue boxes (`x`) in the orange box (`numbers`), and the inner loop is looping through all the green boxes (`y`) in the blue box (`x`) that it was given.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, totally understand it but. i wonder why this first for(int y:x) couldnt run this println? Why it had to pass his value to variable y ? Because they have the same value.As you said: "For each of the elements in x, place it's value in y and run the code below. This is the part i dont understand why it had to pass the value to y ?

Comment: Because `x` is an array of ints. You need to iterate over each value of `x`. In this case, you are setting `y` equal to each value. This is the same as setting `x` equal to each `int[]` in the `int[][]` called numbers.

Comment: @miljannet See my edit with the graphic for details.

Comment: Thank you Andrew ! Got it now, thank you a lot guys.

Answer (score 6):

First, we are going to rename `numbers` to `grid`, `x` to `row`, and `y` to `cell`. Let's break it down.

`for (int x[]:numbers)` can be rewritten as `for (int[] row : grid)`. This iterates over all `int[]`s stored in `grid`. For each `int[]`, `row` is set to that `int[]`.

The inner loop, `for (int y : x)`, rewritten as `for (int cell : row)` is iterating over all of the values of `row`, which is an `int[]`, and setting `cell` equal to each value. The first time the outer then inner loops run, `row` is equal to `grid[0]` and `cell` is equal to `row[0]`, or `grid[0][0]`. This continues until every value in `grid` has been used.

Comment: Got it now why it is better to use int[] x, but still dont get it what is this for(int y:x) loop doing ? I understnad that x inherits the numbers from array numbers.But why this int y needs to inherits numbers from variable x ? y is same as x everytime ?

Answer (score 1):

The first loop describes the index of the first array (`length == 3`), in which again there are arrays with `length == 5`. The second loop is to walk through your numbers array and print out every single value in a new line.

So it goes from `[0][0...4]` to `[1][0...4]` and last `[2][0...4]` and prints out every value.

Comment: The shorter version of the loop, called an enhanced for loop, allows for iteration over an array or collection without maintaining a counter variable. It's called syntactical sugar; it's a quicker way to do something. Suit yourself ;)

Comment: Actually, I do like the enhanced for loop because it is less error prone (less code overall) and easier to read.

Comment: @nrubin29
Hi both, am I wrong when guessing that the enhanced for loop only can increment +1 ?

Or would it then look like this when incrementing +3:
`for(int cell : row+3) {}`

Thx!

Comment: `row` is an `int[]`, therefore you cannot add 3 to `row`. If you want to iterate over every third element, you'd use a standard for loop that increments the counter by 3.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional array is actually an array of (1-dimensional) arrays. Each row or column (depending on how you think of your 2D array) in an `int[][]` is a `int[]` and each item in there is a simple `int`.

With some (hopefully) less confusing names, your code becomes

```
int[][] grid = new int[5][5];

for (int[] row : grid)
{
    for(int cell : row)
    {
        System.out.println(cell);
    }
}
```

So the outer loop iterates over rows while the inner loop iterates over the elements inside those rows (and it's a different row each time) until the loop has visited every cell in the grid once.

Comment: The renaming of variables is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x[]:numbers)
```

Here you iterate over numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], and the value of numbers[i] is put into the variable x. Then x is a one-dimensional array you iterate over in:

```
for(int y:x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the key point:  There's actually no such thing as a "two-dimensional array".  Just as an `int[]` is an array of `int`, an `int[][]` is an array of `int[]`.  When you say `myArray[1][2]`, it's not really going into coordinate (1, 2) of a grid.  `myArray` is an array of arrays, so `myArray[1]` gives you an array, which is indexed by `[2]`.

Or, to rewrite the first part of your example:

```
int numbers[][] = new int[3][5];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int[] array = numbers[i];
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        array[j]=(i+1)*(j+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that there's "no such thing" as a 2D array. Oracle seems to think there is.

Comment: There is such a thing as a 2D array, just not in Java. The best Java can do is a 1D array of references to further arrays. It's not the same, because they could be anywhere on the heap. This means that if you want performance, you sometimes have to use a single 1D array and compute the indices yourself.